# ISIN symbol pairs for DAX, MDAX, SDAX, TecDAX and Nasdaq-100

Tags: programming

I am looking for a simple source for ISIN-symbol pairs for DAX, MDAX, SDAX, TecDAX and Nasdaq-100? I can't find anything on Yahoo and possible sources only offer searches for individual stocks, but I would like to get lists for all stocks in an index.

Do you know a source or technical solution?

Comment: I found this answer helpful and will test it tomorrow:
https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/70155/43387

Answer (score 0):

DAX: DE0008469008

MDAX: DE0008467416

SDAX: DE0009653386

TecDAX: DE0007203275

NASDAQ 100: US6311011026

See https://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/index/nasdaq-100 and for the others replace the last part of the URL or use the search function (look for entries with category “index”)

At least for the DAX family these should be as good as official since these indices are calculated by Deutsche Börse who owns the Frankfurt Exchange (XFRA).